# Can a Riemannian metric always be induced by an immersion $F$? (I use that for any tangent vector, there exists a vector field)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

[From this question and the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268535/does-the-riemannian-metric-induced-by-a-diffeomorphism-f-exist-for-a-reason-ot), we can relax $F$ from diffeomorphism to local diffeomorphism. My question is further relaxing from local diffeomorphism to immersion.

1. Is Part A (the inner product part) satisfied?

   - I was able to show that that $F$ is an immersion at $p$ is equivalent to saying that if $\langle X_p, X_p \rangle'_p = 0$, then $X_p=0_p$, the zero tangent vector in $T_pN$. This is one-third of the positive-definiteness part of the inner product part.
   - I think the other two-thirds of the positive-definiteness part, the symmetry part and bilinearity part are satisified **without** assuming $F$ immersion.
2. As for Part B (the smooth part), I'm going to use [Exercise 1.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw9PF.png) and its [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADhoW.png). **Is this correct?**

   - 2.1. Let $X,Y \in \mathfrak X(N)$ and $p \in N$. By [Exercise 1.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw9PF.png) and its [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADhoW.png), we can write $\langle X, Y\rangle'$ locally as $(\langle X, Y\rangle')_p = (\langle X, Y\rangle'|_{U_p})_p = (\langle A,B \rangle \circ F)(p)$, through writing $\langle X, Y\rangle'|_{U_p} = \langle A,B \rangle \circ F$, for some $A,B \in \mathfrak X(M)$ where $U_p$ is a neighborhood of $p$ in $N$ and $A_{F(p)} = F_{*,p} X_p$ and $B_{F(p)} =  F_{*,p} Y_p$.
   - 2.2. By assumed smoothness of $\langle, \rangle$, we have $\langle A, B\rangle \in C^{\infty}M$.
   - 2.3. Therefore, by (2.1) and (2.2), each $\langle X, Y\rangle'|_{U_p}$ is smooth as a composition of smooth maps $F$ and $\langle A, B\rangle$.
   - 2.4. A map $G: P \to Q$ of smooth manifolds is smooth if each $r \in P$ has a neighborhood $V_r$ in $P$ such that $G: V_r \to Q$ is smooth.
   - 2.5. Therefore, by (2.3) and (2.4), the entire $\langle X, Y\rangle'$ is smooth.

---

**Update 1**: It appears this is true, is called "pullback metric" and is what Paulo Mourão proved [in the aforementioned question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3277064/636532). Therefore, I hope this is not a duplicate because I gave my own proof (at least for Part B).

**Update 2**: It appears I don't assume $F$ immersion for Part B. Or do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everything you wrote is correct except 2.1:

For each $p\in N$ you want to find smooth vectorfields $A,B \in \mathfrak X(M)$ such that there is is a neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ with $(A\circ F)_{|U}=(F_{*}\circ X)_{|U}$ and $(B\circ F)_{|U}=(F_{*}\circ Y)_{|U}$ since then

$$\langle X,Y\rangle'_{|U}=\langle F_{*}\circ X,F_{*}\circ Y\rangle_{|U}=\langle A\circ F,B\circ F\rangle_{|U}=(\langle A,B\rangle\circ F)_{|U}$$

is smooth as a composition of smooth functions. Here $F_{*}:TN\to TM$ is the differential of $F$.

While it is true that such $A,B$ can be found if $F$ is an immersion it does **not** follow from Excercise 1.5 and its proof:  there you only get  $(A\circ F)(p)=(F_{*}\circ X)(p)$ while you need the equality to hold in a whole neighbourhood arround $p$.

Comment: Thanks Chiara! (To reflect name change)